# Add values in the same row php

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to add values to a table using a loop, but the values are introduced into the next row, (ex. in the first column - first value, in the second column - next value but a incremented row, and so on) What' wrong with my code?

```
for ($i = 1; $i < $nbcol; $i++) {      


mysql_query("INSERT INTO $table1 ($col[$i]) VALUES ('".$_POST['name'.$i]."')"); 
};
mysql_close($dbconnection);
```

Comment: do an update not insert

Comment: ^ but also don't pass user input direct to your SQL. That opens you to sql injections.

Comment: bit unsure what youre trying to achieve. do you mean you have a number of values that you want to set in each row?

Comment: a before, after, and Desired After data sample could bring a bit of clarity

Comment: how many values/colums do you have? You have to run the query once outside of the for loop if many or write the query explicitly if few

Comment: I have another php with a table that get values from 11 fields, name0,name1,...., name11. I try to insert this values in the main table. But the code inserts, name0 in the col0 , name1  in the col1 next row......., i want to put them in the same row. Why the code increments the row?

Comment: because you are doing separate inserts instead of glomming them all into 1 crafted insert statement. the db engine does what you tell it rather than reading your mind

Answer (score 1):

finally, I succeeded. 
This is the code:

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
include 'variable.php';
$query = "Select * from $table1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$nbcol = mysql_num_fields($result);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO $table1 ($col[1]) VALUES ('".$_POST['name1']."')"); 
for ( $i = 2; $i < $nbcol; $i++ ) {
$colname = mysql_field_name($result, $i);
mysql_query("UPDATE $table1 SET $colname ='".$_POST['name'.$i]."' WHERE $col[0] = '".$_POST['name0']."' ");
}
header("Location: index.php");
mysql_close($dbconnection);
?>
```

and in the php file which are the inputs,

```
<td><input name="name0" type="text" value="<?php echo $num_rows+1; ?>"></td>
```

inserts the following row, ex. there are 30 rows($num_rows), the code will insert 30+1(31), in the first field, which are the row into insert the values

thank you @Drew Pierce for the point, first is making an insert for the second field, and then update for the other.

Answer (score 0):

try to error log and see what the problem is by using mysql_error and then report back what the problem is here if you need further help.

```
for ($i = 1; $i < $nbcol; $i++) {      


mysql_query("INSERT INTO $table1 ($col[$i]) VALUES ('".$_POST['name'.$i]."')") or die(mysql_error()); 
};
mysql_close($dbconnection);
```

But honestly  you should not be increasing your columns. They should be keeping the same right? so why are you saying

```
$col[$i]
```

Just add the column name here and then iterate through your post data if it is monotonically increasing